# How to make multiple HTTP requests with RxJS and merge the response into one payload and map it to another action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

As per the title, I've been trying to figure out a way to make multiple HTTP calls from an action payload and basically merging all results into a single array and then map the result to another action as a payload.

Here is my existing code, it works but it seems it seem not merging both responses and only cares about last response from the request's response, perhaps I'm using the wrong operator, I'm just picking up RxJS and trying different things to learn, hopefully somebody is able to explain where I'm going wrong.

Any help or direction is much appreciated.

```
{
    type: 'FETCH_DATA',
    payload: {
        key: 'standings',
        value: [
                'http://url-1',
                'http://url-2'
        ],
    })
}


// The epic is listening to the above action

const fetchDataEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType('FETCH_DATA'),
    mergeMap(action => {
        const { key, value } = action.payload;
        if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length) {
            const makeRequest = value.map((x, i) => ajax.getJSON(value[i]))

            return (
                forkJoin(
                    makeRequest,
                    response => {
                        return ({
                            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED',
                            payload: {
                                key,
                                value: response,
                            },
                        })
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    })
);
```

NOTE: Both request's response is in same JSON format with same properties, but different data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it only cares about the **last** response, but the **first** one.

That's because if you want to **customize the response** from `forkJoin`, the second(or last, in case the first one isn't an array) argument(which is a function) accepts **multiple arguments**, which are the responses from the supplied requests.

Thus, this is the change I'd perform in order to get the whole array of responses.

```js
/* ... */
forkJoin(
    makeRequest,
    (...response) => {
        return ({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED',
            payload: {
                key,
                value: response,
            },
        })
    }
)
/*
```

#### Edit: sending the merged responses to another action

This can be achieved by using the [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator, which is commonly used when you have to deal with side effects.

```js
(
 mergeMap(action => { ... }),
 tap(action => sendToOtherAction(action))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it works but I still see the same result as before, but using spread operator didn't change much.

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve is to send another action after you got the merged responses, right? By ‘merged’, I understand they are grouped into an array. What’s left would be to sent another action, right?

Comment: Yes, suppose we have 2 ajax calls, make both calls and on success merge both responses into single array and send that as payload to another action.

Comment: Thank you :) will give it a try again

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you're using rxjs' ajax function, which should already give you observables. In that case, forkJoin should give you both values as an array once the all the observable have emitted values. And then you can added to your action payload with the map function.

```js
const requestArrays = [1, 2].map(i => {
  return rxjs.ajax.ajax.getJSON(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${i}`);
});

rxjs.forkJoin(requestArrays)
  .pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(resp => {
      console.log('Part 1: Response so far: ');
      console.log(resp);
    }),
    rxjs.operators.map(value => {
      return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED',
        payload: {
          value
        }
      };
    }),
    rxjs.operators.tap(resp => {
      console.log('Part 2: Result as a action payload: ');
      console.log(resp);
    }),
  )
  .subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

---

EDIT:
Here is roughly how you would implement it.

```js
const action = {
  type: 'FETCH_DATA',
  payload: {
    value: [
      '1',
      '2'
    ],
  }
};

rxjs.of(action)
.pipe(
    rxjs.operators.mergeMap(action => {
      const requestArrays = action.payload.value.map(i => {
        return rxjs.ajax.ajax.getJSON(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${i}`);
      });
      return rxjs.forkJoin(requestArrays)
      .pipe(
          rxjs.operators.map(value => {
            return {type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED', payload: {value}};
          })
      )
    })
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, I could now see the result in my console, however it fails to complete running, and here is a the error log,

`
TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
`

Comment: A suggestion for when using RxJs from CDN is to destruct the functions like const map = rxjs.operators; and then you can use .pipe(map(val => useVal(val)), I think it makes it a lot more readable and matches the look of code when using imports.

Comment: @ZAD, did you implement it the same way I did in the edit? If you click run snippet, you can see it gives you the right result and no errors.

Comment: @ Cookie Stealer
Yes, strangely enough I followed the exact same thing but yet couldn't get it working, it can't be your snippet as that's running perfectly fine, perhaps need to look at it tomorrow again, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ZAD, If you still can't figure it out by tomorrow, feel free to post your implementation and I can take a look at it and see what's up.